# How Does NADPH Reduce 1,3-BPG?

Tags: biochemistry, photosynthesis

If NADPH returns to being NADP+, then that means one proton and two electrons have been incorporated into 1,3-BPG. If only one proton and one electron were attached to the carbon in 1,3-BPG (removing phosphate), I’d understand, since there’s a single covalent bond between carbon and hydrogen which establishes stable octets. But there’s another electron hanging around. What happens to this one? Or am I totally mistaken about the whole process?

This is the chemical formula for G3P:

[image]

The Lewis diagram below shows the top part:

[image]

As stated, NADPH gave off 2 electrons, yet only one is needed to bond with carbon (orange). Where did the other electron disappear to?

Comment: NADPH is always accompanied by H+, and the electrons reduce as a pair. Otherwise, there will be no balance of charges.

Comment: And after NADPH reduces 1,3-BPG, it goes back to being NADP+. It loses two electrons. In 1,3-BPG, the hydrogen bonds with carbon, contributing one electron to the single covalent bond. My question is where the another electron has gone, if it’s not in 1,3-BPG and not in NADP+.

Comment: Sometimes the electrons react w/ oxygen to form superoxide, or react with surrounding hydrogen to form water

Comment: @Kendall So the electron does go elsewhere, and is not incorporated in G3P, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Single covalent bond is a **shared pair** of electrons. For stable bond there should be 2 atoms with unfilled higher orbitals and at least a pair of electrons that is "distributed" among those slots.

UC Davis have hilarious [page on that](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Theoretical_Chemistry/Chemical_Bonding/General_Principles/Covalent_Bonds).

Comment: I have edited my question to show what I’m talking about better. A proton and one electron may be equivalent to a hydrogen atom, which can bond with a carbon atom. But there’s an extra electron that NADPH gives. What happens to it?